# How to display line break for irregular time series with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a specific needs when i look into Area with missing points of Highchart demo.

I want a line chart with irregular time series data that will break line if no data available on displayed date.

is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer for now which I got the answer straight from the creator of Highchart

you may refer to his answer here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3043#issuecomment-42819076

Answer (score 6):

Placing a `null` in your series data will do this exact thing:

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, null, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CXg3n/).

[image]

Comment: i have a few irregular serieses of which I don't have to put the null

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul, I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `highstock.js` and set [oridinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) parameter as false